# How can I send custom input to meta classifier of Stacking using weka api

Tags: weka

From a research paper "In addition to stacking across all classifier outputs, we also evaluate stacking using only the aggregate output of each resampled (bagged) base classifier. For example, the outputs of all 10 SVM classifiers are averaged and used as a single level 0 input to the meta learner." 
I am wondering how can I implement this. Actually I need to implement this for my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the average of the 10 classifiers you can add a voting classifier as one of the base classifiers for stacking. The voting classifier can use as many SVM classifiers as you need. 
if you want to use the predictions of the SVM classifiers also as inputs for the stacking classifier, you can add SVM classifiers next to the voting classifiers (as base classifiers for stacking). However this would not be very effective.

Otherwise you can modify the code by yourself as Weka is an open source.